# XML extract with php foreach is not looping

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to make this loop, but it is only returning the first values.

XML

```
<catalog>
<dd>
    <categoryassignment categoryid="3d-magic" productid="000000000000109330_PURPLE/ BLUE"/>

    <categoryassignment categoryid="3d-magic" productid="000000000000109330_PURPLE/ BLUE/ ORANGE"/>

    <categoryassignment categoryid="3d-magic" productid="000000000000109330_RED/ GREEN/ YELLOW"/>

    <categoryassignment categoryid="3d-magic" productid="000000000000109335_BLUE/YELLOW"/>

    <categoryassignment categoryid="3d-magic" productid="000000000000109335_PURPLE/ORANGE"/>

    <categoryassignment categoryid="3d-magic" productid="000000000000115881_GREEN/PURPLE"/>

    <categoryassignment categoryid="3d-magic" productid="000000000000115881_ORANGE/BLUE"/>

    <categoryassignment categoryid="3d-magic" productid="000000000000115881_RED/YELLOW"/>

    <categoryassignment categoryid="3d-magic" productid="000000000109329001"/>

    <categoryassignment categoryid="3d-magic" productid="000000000109329002"/>

    <categoryassignment categoryid="3d-magic" productid="000000000109335001"/>

    <categoryassignment categoryid="3d-magic" productid="000000000111568001"/>

    <categoryassignment categoryid="3d-magic" productid="000000000111568002"/>
</dd>
```

PHP

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("store.xml") or die("Failed to create an object");

foreach($xml->children() as $books) { 
echo $books->categoryassignment['categoryid'];echo $books->categoryassignment['productid'];echo "<br>";}
```

From the example here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to change how you are referencing the data. If you first do a quick debug by doing:

```
print_r($xml);
```

You will see that you have an object like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [dd] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [categoryassignment] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [categoryid] => 3d-magic
                                    [productid] => 000000000000109330_PURPLE/ BLUE
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [categoryid] => 3d-magic
                                    [productid] => 000000000000109330_PURPLE/ BLUE/ ORANGE
                                )
                        )
         ... etc ...
```

With this knowledge, you can then easily see where you need to put your `foreach`. It would be like this (with a slight change to `$books` inside):

```
foreach($xml->dd->categoryassignment as $books) { 
    echo $books['categoryid'];
    echo ' ';
    echo $books['productid'];
    echo "<br>\n";
}
```

And that results as:

> ```
> 3d-magic 000000000000109330_PURPLE/ BLUE
> 3d-magic 000000000000109330_PURPLE/ BLUE/ ORANGE
> 3d-magic 000000000000109330_RED/ GREEN/ YELLOW
> 3d-magic 000000000000109335_BLUE/YELLOW
> 3d-magic 000000000000109335_PURPLE/ORANGE
> 3d-magic 000000000000115881_GREEN/PURPLE
> 3d-magic 000000000000115881_ORANGE/BLUE
> 3d-magic 000000000000115881_RED/YELLOW
> 3d-magic 000000000109329001
> 3d-magic 000000000109329002
> 3d-magic 000000000109335001
> 3d-magic 000000000111568001
> 3d-magic 000000000111568002
> ```

Comment: Great that worked thanks. Looks more simple than i thought!